# jQuery validate multiple select dependent on another field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validate plugin and cannot get it to validate dependent upon another field.  The same logic below WILL validate a normal select, but just not a multiple select.  Here's my jFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eFCBD/)

In the Fiddle, I am using a normal select, but when I change it to the multiple select, it breaks.  Looking for a solution.  Thanks.

jQuery:

```
$("#my_form").validate({
    rules: {
        'my_choice_name': {
            required: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    //this logic works (tested on another field name/value), just not on the multiple select field:
                    if ($('#my_alt_select_id').val() !== '3') {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having a multiple select list, the `.val()` is an array.

To see if X val is checked, you need to use `indexOf()`.

```
if($('#my_alt_select_id').val().indexOf('3') == -1)
```

Comment: Awesome.  Works as expected.  Thank you!